Haven::write_xpt don't output non-ASCII character “°” correctly
a <- data.frame(b = "History of moderate (25-40°) to severe (>40°)")
haven::write_xpt(a, tempfile("a.xpt"))

https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/751

Perhaps you have to provide the proper unicode for the degree symbol, ''(25-40\u00B0)", rather than the representation (what it looks like). 'history of 25\u00B0' [1] "history of 25°"Welcome to Stackoverflow.
